# What is the difference between two sentences below?

Tags: word-difference

1.He is an uncle with a beer gut.

2.He is an uncle who has a beer gut.

Thank you for your answers.

And I really wonder if they are correct and natural.Because I'm not good at English and I'm studing it now.

Comment: The meaning is the same.

Comment: Either is ok, maybe the second one is a bit better. I would use "beer belly" though.

Comment: @user3169 But is the sentence idiomatic? Does it sounds natural? What's the point of saying that someone is "an uncle"? "That man have a few nephews and a beer belly" sounds strange to me.

Comment: Much appreciated.